# How to make a button position independent using OOCSS?

Tags: oocss

I have a button with the following style:

```
.btn 
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #555555;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    font-family:OpenSansRegular;
    font-size:15px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

As I reckon, using OOCSS principles, we should separate visual from structure.
Something like this (I would assume - correct me if I'm wrong):

```
.btn 
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}

.skin
{
    background-color: #555555;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    font-family:OpenSansRegular;
    font-size:15px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

But what if I want to use the exact same configurations for another button, except for the floating position which I would like to remove, how should I do it? Isn't OOCSS being restrictive by coupling the positioning in the structure?

Answer (score 0):

This likely depends on what exactly the structure you actually have is, but I would likely do something like the following which still follows OOCSS principles:

```
.btn { /* Default button structure properties */
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.float-right { /* More specific button structure properties */
    float: right;
}
.skin { /* Default button skin properties */
    background-color: #555555;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    font-family: OpenSansRegular;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
 }
```

The actual class names could be different, but given you only have one more specific property,  I think the specific name makes sense in this case.